# .Net centralied logging with management interface

Tags: .net, logging

There is already alot of discution about which logging framework is best for .Net.

Log4Net
EnterpriseLibrary
NLog
...

My question is if there is a product to manage a centralized repository of logs.

Imagine I choose any of the above logging frameworks and point several applications logs to a central server. What I'm looking for a server product that helps visualize and manage those logs. Preferably with a web interface.

Is there such a product?

Answer (score 2):

[Seq](http://getseq.net) is another option to consider; it's an on-premises server with a web interface and some interesting features around structured data storage and querying.

It is commercial (I work on it :)) but has a very useful free edition that suits a lot of folks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to pay for your software, Gibraltar software have a good solution, but it is reasonably expensive. (http://GibraltarSoftware.com).

Comment: I already stumble into this one, but the price tag is realy high. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Depending on your number of users you might check out our SaaS option and / or see if you qualify for our Micro ISV discounts.  For small companies we offer discounts of around 50% on licenses.

Comment: GIBRALTAR is now FREE.  See more details posted as an additional answer on this page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question...searching for 'log4net nlog viewer web' with a search enginge of your choice (e.g. google) will give a lot of possible desktop and web applications for analysing centralized log files.

One commercial example is http://www.l4ndash.com
One open source example is http://sourceforge.net/projects/gamutlogviewer/

Comment: Yes l4ndash is the kind of product I'm looking for, but it is specific for log4net. I'm still trying to find something more generic, like Gibraltar but cheaper